# cypher query to find nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

In example http://gist.neo4j.org/?8526106 , suppose i dont know the name of the amazon node, its just a random node which i am looking for.

How i can find these kind of nodes which have further outgoing relationships. In my graphdata i have 4000 nodes and two type of relationships one is CALLS and other is IS CALLING, but i want to have only is call relationship with nodes, 
i tried this query but still i am getting the IS_CALLING and start nodes as well.

```
match path=(n)-->(m) 
WHERE ALL (r IN rels(path) WHERE type(r)='CALLS'AND NOT type(r)='IS_CALLING')           collect(path) as PATHS
return PATHS limit 100;
```

in result i am still getting the relationship type "IS_CALLING". Also i tried very simple one like

```
START a=node(*), b=node(*), c=node(*)
match p=(a)-[:CALLS]->(b)-[:CALLS*0..1]->(c) 
WHERE NOT ((c)-[:CALLS|IS_CALLING]->()) 
return p limit 100;
```

to see if a is connected to b and b is connected to c show me the nodes like which are not further connected to anything no but again IS_CALLING is there. 
please correct me if i am doing something wrong, or i am missing something. 
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may just be an issue with how Neo4j displays results. If two nodes in the result are connected, all their relationships are displayed in the graphical view even if they're not actually part of the match.

I tried the same query structure on my own data and saw the same result in the graphical output, where the `NOT`-type relationships appeared along with the selected type. However, try something like this:

```
MATCH path=(n)-[R]->(m) 
WHERE ALL (r IN rels(path) WHERE type(r)='CALLS' AND NOT type(r)='IS_CALLING')           
RETURN n, type(R), m LIMIT 100;
```

If you look at the list view rather than graph view, you should see that the actual result only contains the selected relationships you wanted.

Comment: thanks adam, but this did not work as well. still 'IS_CALLING' is there.